# В JavaFX отсутствует FXCollections.observableList

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

При создании *JavaFX* проекта, *Intellij Idea* не находит статический метод `observableArrayList` в классе `FXCollections`, в библиотеке `javafx.collections`.

Все остальные методы тоже не находит, хотя сам класс и методы в нем есть.

В самом классе `FXCollections` есть импорт:

`import com.sun.javafx.collections.annotations.ReturnsUnmodifiableCollection;`

который *Idea* тоже не находит, и его похоже действительно нету в *Jdk*. Возможно, проблема в этом, но не понимаю, как решить.

**Обновление**

Дело в том, что этот импорт
`import com.sun.javafx.collections.annotations.ReturnsUnmodifiableCollection;`
в классе из самой JDK, и в com.sun есть пакет collections, но в нем нет пакета annotations, как нет его и в 
`javafx.collections`
 подозреваю, что в этом и проблема, (может быть из-за некорректного импорта класс и не подключается) но как ее решить, и почему в jdk есть импорт из несуществующего пакета?
Использую JDK 1.8

Как com.sun. может быть лишним в JDK?

Comment: А в том ли пакете идея ищет? `import static javafx.collections.FXCollections.observableArrayList;`

Comment: С какой версией JDK работаете? 1.8?

Comment: Первый комментарий намекает на то, что, возможно, `com.sun.` лишний перед `javafx.`.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась, причиной была моя невнимательность, вместо

ObservableList datas = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

Я написал

```
ObservableList<XYChart.Data> datas = new FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Естественно, такого класса там не было. Спасибо за потраченное время.

Comment: Для уточнений редактируйте вопрос. Ответы только для полноценного решения проблемы в вопросе.

Comment: А вот может. Попробуйте руками начать писать import javafx. и т.д. до FXCollections. Я верю, что решение появится. А импорт com.sun. пакета уберите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Посмотрел я в библиотеки JDK 1.8. Да, в jar'е по пути com.sun.javafx.collections отсутствует пакет annotations и далее. Как пишут на форумах, сие наблюдается с 2015 года. Содержимое искомого интерфейса вот такое: https://github.com/Debian/openjfx/blob/master/buildSrc/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/collections/annotations/ReturnsUnmodifiableCollection.java но оно видимо живёт в силу того, что во всех либах переопределяется (а по сути - определяется заново). Такие вот чудеса и странности. Не смотря на такое "волшебство", всё должно работать.

Comment: А если не работает, попробуйте другой редактор или приведите код Вашего приложения.